# What is the Perl equivalent of PCRE's PCRE_PARTIAL?

Tags: c, regex, perl, pcre

Is there a way for a Perl regular expression to do a partial match, i.e. some variation of the following expression should return true.

```
perl -le 'print "aa" =~ /aaaa/'
```

Here is the equivalent PCRE code that does this.

```
$ cat partial.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcre.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *errptr;
    int erroffset, result;
    pcre *re;

    re = pcre_compile("aaaa", 0, &errptr, &erroffset, NULL);
    if (re == NULL)
        return 42;

    result = pcre_exec(re, NULL, "aa", 2, 0, PCRE_PARTIAL, NULL, 0);

    printf("%d\n", result == PCRE_ERROR_PARTIAL);

    return 0;
}

$ make partial LDFLAGS=-lpcre
cc   -lpcre  partial.c   -o partial

$ ./partial 
1
```

EDIT: The [pcretest](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcretest.html) tool can be used to demonstrate the difference between partial and non-partial matches.  Also include result of matching the regex suggested by @revo in comments.

```
$ pcretest
PCRE version 8.41 2017-07-05

  re> /aaaa/

data> aa
No match

data> aa\P
Partial match: aa
data> aaaa
 0: aaaa

$ pcretest
PCRE version 8.41 2017-07-05

  re> /aaa?a?/

data> aa
 0: aa

data> aa\P
 0: aa
```

Comment: Do you consider this a partial match? `perl -le 'print "aa" =~ /aaa?a?/'`

Comment: Well, for simple cases I just reverse the matches. E.g. `"aaaa" =~ /aa/`, and use that as my 'partial' case.  This would appear to work in your example - is there a reason why it wouldn't 'for real'?

Comment: @revo your example is not strictly a partial match.  I have updated my question to include output from the [pcretest](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcretest.html) tool to illustrate the difference.

Comment: I was trying to shed some light on question. That's kinda simulating *partial match* if what you are trying to match is *partial*. Yet I don't get if this question is asking whether it's possible to do partial matching in Perl or just looks for a workaround to a specific problem.

Comment: @revo Thanks for looking into this.  I have a C program that makes heavy use of pcre_exec(..., PCRE_PARTIAL, ....);.  For now, I am trying to translate it to Perl and be as close as possible to the C code.  I tried to phrase my question according to the [mcve] guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

There is no simple way to do this with Perl regexes. Perl's match operator either returns true (match found) or false (match not found).

There are possible workarounds if you know what pattern you're dealing with (by rewriting the pattern to do partial matching manually), but there's no general solution as far as I'm aware.